# Cannot chat in chat

Tags: support, chat

I'm not able to use chat. It says that my login informations are too old, but it is not true. I also tried various browsers with no success.

Comment: What does http://chat.stackexchange.com/help say?

Comment: @balpha That is interesting, now is everything working. I have no idea what the problem was. Sorry.

Comment: No problem :) If you run into issues again, we have a "when-all-else-fails better-than-nothing" secondary login; be sure to be logged in to gamedev, and then go to http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/chat-stackexchange-login and click the button (works on any other StackExchange site as well).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Ben pointed out, always try

http://chat.stackexchange.com/help

first.

It is also linked under "I'm having trouble logging in to chat" in the faq http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq